# Firefox not supporting min-height

Tags: css, firefox

Have been trying to do a style on firefox using a min-height rule but it doesn't seem to read it setting height to 100% could somehow fix the problem but when I reach the edge of the element the background is cut, I tried to do this with a plain html file a structure like:

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="inner-el">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I use the following css rule:

```
div.inner-el{
width: 90%;
min-height: 65%;
}
```

The min-height does not seem to reflect on the element I'm trying to hit. My firefox version is 62.0.

Comment: try to add in css `body{ height: 100%;}`

Comment: percentage for min-height refers from it's parent height. here your body element does not have any specific height, you have to set height for your body tag first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please give `height` to `body` tag. You can check here.

```css
body{
  height:100vh;
}
div.inner-el{
  width: 90%;
  min-height: 65%;
  background:#000;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="inner-el">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```